# JavaFX How to check internet connection with thread

Tags: java, javafx

I work on a javafx application and that application gets some data from a website and shows some data on UI. When internet connection is lost, program ends immediately but I want program shouldn't close. There is a circle on my UI and when internet connection is lost it's color should turn into red and it should check internet connection every 3 sec. To do that, I catch an exception from my `setValues` method.

Following exception occurs when program can't reach the website.But when it catch exception it calls run method itself and catch exception again immediately and it do that again and again, due to which it uses a lot of memory . How can I avoid of that problem.

Code is shown in image, kindly review and give feedback.

[image: Code]

Comment: you catch an Exception to check if there is an internet connection? why don't you just ping www.google.com ?

Comment: We probably cannot help without a [mcve]: The source of the memory issue is unclear (or whether there actually is an issue; memory may just not be reclaimed by the garbage collector at the time you measure it). There probably is no way around setting up a new connection though, whether you do this from a loop or some other way...

Comment: You could use a [`ScheduledService`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/concurrent/ScheduledService.html) that returns a boolean indicating current connection status. When the connection succeeds, return true, when the connection fails, return false. Then react to the value by listening to the `lastValue` property.

Comment: Please post [code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), not pictures of code; `while (true)…Platform.runLater(new Runnable()…)` is a [doomed](https://dzone.com/articles/java-what-limit-number-threads); consider `javafx.concurrent.Service<V>` instead.